# Check if Smart-Card Reader turned on or not

Tags: c#

I've been googling for a long time looking for an adequate example so I can check if "Smartcard-reader" is turned on or not. I noticed the change in Device Manager as in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENkBZ.png)

the only thing i could find for now is this PDF, but i couldn't come up with a solution yet.
http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf

How could I check through the code itself whether this Smartcard-Leser is turned on via USB or not?

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: Does the device appear if it's turned off? From the computer's perspective is turned off the same as unplugged?

Comment: Hi John, the device does not appear if it is turned off

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution :

```
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            if(queryObj["Description"].Equals("ACR122 Smart Card Reader"))
            {
                //smard card reader found
            }
        }
```